# Mysql Query correction

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get all the videos related to the video which is currently playing ie get all videos of the current video user OR get all the videos of the current video categories OR get all the videos of the current video tags, I tried the following tow query structures but I get only one record in both the cases, 23 in the query is the current video id. Any help would be appreciated.

I have the following tables{fields}

- videos_table {vid,title,duration,url,date},
- users_table {uid,uname},
- categories_table {cid,vid},
- tags_table {tid,vid},
- likes_table {id,vid},
- views_table {id,vid}

QUERY 1:.

```
SELECT v.title, v.duration,v.url ,v.date,u.uname, count(distinct l.id) AS likes,count(distinct vt.vid) AS views  
FROM videos_table  AS  v 
JOIN users_table  AS u ON u.uid=v.uid 
JOIN likes_table  AS l ON l.vid=v.vid
JOIN views_table  AS vt ON vt.vid=v.vid 
JOIN categories_table  AS  c ON c.vid=v.vid
JOIN tags_table AS t ON t.vid=v.vid
WHERE u.uid=(SELECT uid FROM videos_table WHERE vid=23) OR 
c.cid IN ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  cid) from categories_table WHERE   c.vid=23 ) OR 
t.tid IN ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  tid) FROM tags_table   WHERE vid=23 )
```

QUERY 2:.

```
SELECT v.title, v.duration,v.url ,v.date,u.name, count(distinct l.id) AS likes,count(distinct vt.vid) AS views  
FROM videos_table  AS  v, users_table  AS u,likes_table  AS l,views_table  AS vt ,categories_table  AS  c,tags_table AS t
WHERE (u.uid=v.uid AND l.vid=v.vid AND c.vid=v.vid AND vt.vid=v.vid) 
AND 
(u.uid=(SELECT uid from videos_table  WHERE vid=23) OR 
c.cid IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cid) FROM categories_table WHERE vid=23) OR
vt.tid IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tid) FROM tags_table WHERE vid=23))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you know the sentence "UNION ALL"?

Comment: there is a mistook in the first query `u.uid=(SELECTuid FROM.....)`

Comment: Can a user like a video they haven't viewed?

Comment: user can like a video after visiting the video page, like youtube,